# Saving and Adding to A List (Android)

Tags: java, android

Plain and, hopefully simply...

-What I would like to do is make a list of strings.

-I would like to add to this list while in the application.

-Finally, I want to get each String from this list.

This must be saved somehow so that when you close it and open it back up, the list will save... 
How should I get around to this? SharedPreferences? An SQL Database? What should I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I vote SharedPreferences since it will be faster and will persist throughout the life span of the application.

If you need to have the saved data made available during the next time the app is run, you will most likely want to use a DB